# How to write mysqli_result

Tags: php, html, mysql

How do I set the mysqli_result on the last line?

```
if(isset($_POST['thename']) === true && empty($_POST['thename']) === false) {
    $getVal = mysqli_real_escape_string($cutConn_db, trim($_POST['thename']));

    require '../db/cb_bz.php';
    $query = mysql_query("
    SELECT 'photos'.'theurl' FROM 'names' WHERE 'names'.'thename'".$getVal."'");
    $resultA = mysqli_query($cutConn_db, $query);
    $rowz = mysqli_fetch_row($resultA);
    $tota_rowz = $rowz[0];

    echo($tota_rowz !== 0) ? mysqli_result($query, 0, 'theurl') : 'Not found.';
}
```

Comment: Why are you mixing mysql and mysqli functions?!

Comment: i know to do this in mysql. But I'm asking you how to write when using mysqli?

Comment: How about some good old RTFM? http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.statements.php

Comment: @deceze thanks - was expecting something more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$query = "SELECT 'photos'.'theurl' FROM 'names' WHERE 'names'.'thename'".$getVal."'";
$resultA = mysqli_query($cutConn_db, $query);
```

is enough.

I think you need [mysqli_num_rows](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)
Than you can check via `$rowCount = mysqli_num_rows($resultA);` if you received a result.
Than just do:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($resultA)) {
    printf ("%s \n", $row[0]);
}
```